# I'm looking for an adjective in English which describes the below qualities for a new year

Tags: single-word-requests

RE:  Work, your Job, the Company

- Prosperous, but not in the monetary sense, necessarily
- A year in which many projects that need to be addressed, are
  completed with above-average results
- Significant improvement in Department's reputation in the company

The word should fit into the sentence

> Happy New Year! It’s going to be a busy, but _____ one. We’ve got a lot of work to do, but I’m on board 110%

Comment: Word should fit into the sentence "Happy New Year!  It’s going to be a busy, but _____ one.  We’ve got a lot of work to do, but I’m on board 110%."

Comment: *productive* and *rewarding* (give and take).

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a work-related sentence, you could use the word *productive*:

> achieving or producing a significant amount or result. -- [Google defn](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Aproductive)

Otherwise, I'd probably go with *prosperous* as it denotes success.

Answer (score 4):

You could consider using [**fruitful**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fruitful?q=fruitful+) which means:

> Producing good or helpful results; productive:

It is synonymous with productive and it doesn't have much monetary sense in it.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Or [**successful**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/successful):

> having the correct or desired result : ending in success

[Merriam-Webster]

I would choose **fruitful** between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I like the word *splendid* in this context.

Do you feel it fits your requirements?

> 1. gorgeous; magnificent; sumptuous. Synonyms: luxurious, dazzling, imposing. Antonyms: squalid.
> 2. grand; superb, as beauty. Synonyms: majestic, elegant, first-rate.
> 3. **distinguished or glorious, as a name, reputation, victory**, etc. Synonyms: renowned, famed, famous, illustrious, eminent, conspicuous,
>      celebrated, remarkable, brilliant; noble. Antonyms: ordinary,
>      unremarkable, mediocre; ignoble.
> 4. strikingly admirable or fine: splendid talents. Antonyms: modest, poor.
> 5. **excellent, fine, or very good**: to have a splendid time.
> 6. brilliant in appearance, color, etc. Antonyms: dull, drab.

[Source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/splendid)